# Problem in establishing a connection between two android emulators

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I m making an application in ANDROID which will be used at two ends. I want every end to work as client and Server both to run chat on them. Just to check it,  only Client is running on One machine and Server on another. But when I start, Client Emulator is unable to make connection to server emulator.

I m using Sockets to make connections between the two. Client Machine's IP Adress is 192.168.77.62 and my server is running  on 192.168.77.56 and listening on port 4444.

What IP/Port I should use on emulator?? Should I make any changes in any thing there?? Can Any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation on [forwarding ports](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports).